# INSERT INTO via html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can somebody help me with this form? 
I have a table with 3 INT-columns (danni, lenni, anders). I would like this form to insert a new row with the numbers I write in the fields every time I use it. It does insert a new row, but no matter what number I type it only insert '0' in the table.

```
<?php
// Connection

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$danni = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['danni']);
$lenni = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['lenni']);
$anders = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['anders']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO ligabs3 (danni, lenni, anders) VALUES ('$danni', '$lenni', '$anders')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Records Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<p>
<label for="danni">Danni:</label>
<input type="text" name="danni" id="danni">
</p>
<p>
<label for="lenni">Lenni:</label>
<input type="text" name="lenni" id="lenni">
</p>
<p>
<label for="anders">Anders:</label>
<input type="text" name="anders" id="anders">
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Add Records">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: `$_REQUEST` must be `$_POST`

Comment: you're using this in one file, so it's automatically inserting 0's as soon as you load it. Use `!empty()` / `isset()`.

Comment: btw, what is the schema for this? and the type/length of those columns?

Comment: you're not responding to comments, ok. well, if you want more help from me, you'll need to ping me directly.

Comment: Jens - Okay, I will try to learn about it :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, that I didn't answer you. I'm very new at all of this, and this is actually a code, that I found online and have tried to modify, so it suitet my database, but I can understand from you, that there's a little more work to it, than I thought :) 
So, I'm not sure where you want me to use the codes you're writing, but I'll look into it :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    there are so many errors in your code. when you refresh page code will execute and insert in database. not after submit form. everytime on page refresh it will insert.
    name is compulsory for submit button.
 try this.
    <?php
    if($_POST['addrecord']){
    // Connection

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Escape user inputs for security
    $danni = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['danni']);
    $lenni = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['lenni']);
    $anders = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['anders']);

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ligabs3 (danni, lenni, anders) VALUES ('$danni', '$lenni', '$anders')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
    } else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Records Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <p>
    <label for="danni">Danni:</label>
    <input type="text" name="danni" id="danni">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="lenni">Lenni:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lenni" id="lenni">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="anders">Anders:</label>
    <input type="text" name="anders" id="anders">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="addrecord" value="Add Records">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
 <?php
if($_POST['addNewRecords']){

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$danni = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['danni']);
$lenni = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lenni']);
$anders = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['anders']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO ligabs3 (danni, lenni, anders) VALUES ('$danni', '$lenni', '$anders')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}


mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Records Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
<p>
<label for="danni">Danni:</label>
<input type="text" name="danni" id="danni">
</p>
<p>
<label for="lenni">Lenni:</label>
<input type="text" name="lenni" id="lenni">
</p>
<p>
<label for="anders">Anders:</label>
<input type="text" name="anders" id="anders">
</p>
<input type="submit" name="addNewRecords" value="Add Records">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```